# Apache Spark : Joining multiple datasources

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to understand the new external data source API.
Say I have 3 datasources which have a Column BC. I want to create paritions such that, data from all the datasources which have same value for column bc , is loaded into same machine. Any suggestion is most welcome.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented to @G Quintana answer, I don't think it is possible to guarantee that the partition containing the values for a given BC value (let's say BC1) in the first data source is put on the same worker as the partition containing BC1 in the second or third data source, because you cannot state how partitions are assigned to physical nodes.

The only way to get this, up to me, is to create a new RDD which is the union of you three sources and repartition the resulting RDD.

Moreover, I would suggest to use a different approach for repartitioning than the one proposed by @G Quintana, i.e.: write your own `Partitioner`, as described here https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html in the chapter **Custom Partitioners**. In this way you won't have to create a `PairRDD`, but you can just repartition your RDD as you need.

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks for u comment. I want to do partitioning at the read time. Regarding the union point u made, if i have quite big amount of data, how does the union actually work. First data is read into multiple workers corresponding to 3 workers, and whatever is present in the worker it will be union, then there will be shuffling of data ? is my understanding correct, and hows the logic of shuffling decided.

Comment: Well nothing compels an RDD to be stored all on the same worker. An RDD can be stored across multiple workers, but a partition of it is stored in a given worker. Moreover `union` is a transformation, i.e. it won't trigger any action. It will be executed when an action is performed later on. If a partitioner is set over the RDD you are working with - as it is for you -,  it will be preserved, so the amount of data transferred over the network is minimized (look at comments in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PartitionerAwareUnionRDD.scala).

Comment: Today I ordered the book u mentioned, just one more question, If i have 3 steps in my processing, as the processing is lazy, so they would be executed in one go, so whats the relationship between partitioning and workers

Comment: Well, actually executing everything in one go doesn't affect what happens, but only when it happens. Your RDD is partitioned in n partitions and each partition is assigned to a worker (it tries to exploit data locality to improve performance); so each worker may have an arbitrary number of partition of your RDD. I hope I have answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you something like

`// Convert your RDD into a (Key,Value) PairRDD
    val dataByBc=data.map(row => (row.getBc(), row))
    // Repartition 
    val dataByBcPart = dataByBc.partitionBy(HashPartitioner(1000))`

Comment: I think your answer address having all the rows from a SINGLE data source to be partitioned accordingly to what asked, but here the problem is that there are three data sources and I think there is no way to guarantee that the partition containing the values for a given BC value (let's say BC1) in the first data source is put on the same worker as the partition containing BC1 in the second or third data source. This can be achieved only if your `dataByBc` is the union of the three sources.

Comment: I think that if  key and partitioner are same for your 3 RDDs, they will be colocated.

Comment: I don't think so, because you cannot choose which your workers are and maybe the first RDD is on a set of workers and the second one on a different set. It **may** be as you say, but there is no way to guarantee that. Moreover if the three RDD are different, also their partitions will be different, so it will fail again for sure.